# How to call an API platform endpoint from a Symfony command

Tags: symfony, command, api-platform.com

I have a working API platform endpoint, which supports `POST`, `PATCH` & `GET`. Just for an example, it's a book endpoint:
[/api/books](http:///api/books)

Now, I have a new task of creating a Symfony command, which will have a part where I'll be creating a new `Book` object and will save it in the database.

I am into the direction of creating a new Service class to normalize the data to `Book` object, then using `EntityManager` to persist the data to DB, but since I have a working `POST` endpoint in API Platform that basically does the same thing, is it possible for me to call that endpoint instead from the Symfony command that I'll be creating?

Comment: Although it certainly is not so optimize as to make a service, for this tasks you can just do a curl request from your command and call your endpoints.

Comment: You have to getting Services from the Service Container. https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container that have you use like that guide in your "task/command"